# Problema ao inserir rodadas em jogo de pedra , papel e tesoura

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom dia , não estou conseguindo implementar um sistema de rodadas nesse jogo , as rodadas devem trocar quando a Mao do jogador se esvaziar. , oque aconteçe agora é que quando a lista jogador e jogador2 se esvaziam o jogo continua a execução com ela vazia , mas oque deveria acontecer era ele sortear novamente as cartas para começar a outra rodada.

```
import random
print("-"*32)
print("jogo de pedra, papel e tesoura")
print("-"*32)
jogador = []
jogador2 = []
escolha1 = ''
escolha2 = ''
aposta = 0
aposta2 = 0
rodada = 0
dinheiro = 0
dinheiro2 = 0
res = 0
res2 = 0
saldo = 0
saldo2 = 0
dinheiro = 1000
dinheiro2 = 1000
rodada = 1
jogo_roda = True
def sorteio_Cartas(jogador,jogador2,rodada):
  for i in range (3):
    a = len(jogador)
    b = len(jogador2)
    p1 = random.randint(1,3)
    p2 = random.randint(1,3)
    rodada += 1
    i += 1
    if p2 == 3:
        jogador.append("Pedra")
    elif p2 == 2:
        jogador.append("Papel")
    else:
        jogador.append("Tesoura")
    if p1 == 3:
        jogador2.append("Pedra")
    elif p1 == 2:
        jogador2.append("Papel")
    else:
        jogador2.append("Tesoura")
return jogador, jogador2 , rodada
def escolha_Cartas(escolha1,jogador):
    if escolha1 in jogador[0]:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha1)
        escolha1 = jogador[0]
        jogador.pop(0)
    elif escolha1 in jogador[1]:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha1)
        escolha1 = jogador[1]
        jogador.pop(1)
    else:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha1)
        escolha1 = jogador[2]
        jogador.pop(2)
return escolha1 , jogador,rodada
```

#### fUNÇÃO PARA O JOGADOR 2 ESCOLHER UMA CARTA

```
def escolha_Cartas2(escolha2,jogador2):
    if escolha2 in jogador2[0]:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha2)
        escolha2 = jogador2[0]
        jogador2.pop(0)
    elif escolha2 in jogador2[1]:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha2)
        escolha2 = jogador2[1]
        jogador2.pop(1)
    else:
        print("A Carta escolhida foi ",escolha2)
        escolha2 = jogador2[2]
        jogador2.pop(2)
return escolha2 , jogador,rodada
```

### COMPARAÇÃO DE QUEM GANHOU A RODADA E QUEM PERDEU!

```
defcomparacao(escolha1,escolha2,aposta,aposta2,dinheiro,dinheiro2,saldo,saldo2,res,res2):
# Comparações de Vitoria jogador 2
 if escolha1 == "Pedra" and escolha2 == "Tesoura":
     print("O Jogador 1 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro -= aposta
     res = aposta + aposta2
     saldo = dinheiro + res
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 - aposta2
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
 elif escolha1 == "Tesoura" and escolha2 == "Papel":
     print("O Jogador 1 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador 2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro -= aposta
     res = aposta + aposta2
     saldo = dinheiro + res
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 - aposta2
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
 elif  escolha1 == "Papel" and escolha2 == "Pedra":
     print("O Jogador 1 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador 2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro -= aposta
     res = aposta + aposta2
     saldo = dinheiro + res
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 - aposta2
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
# Comparações de Vitória jogador 2
 elif escolha2 == "Pedra" and escolha1 == "Tesoura":
     print("O Jogador 2 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador 2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro2 -= aposta2
     res2 = aposta + aposta2
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 + res2
     saldo = dinheiro - aposta
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
 elif escolha2 == "Tesoura" and escolha1 == "Papel":
     print("O Jogador 2 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador 2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro2 -= aposta2
     res2 = aposta + aposta2
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 + res2
     saldo = dinheiro - aposta
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
 elif escolha2 == "Papel" and escolha1 == "Pedra":
     print("O Jogador 2 Ganha!!")
     print("O Jogador 1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador 2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
     dinheiro2 -= aposta2
     res2 = aposta + aposta2
     saldo2 = dinheiro2 + res2
     saldo = dinheiro - aposta
     print("O Saldo do jogador 2 é: ",str(saldo2))
     print("O Saldo do jogador 1 é: ",str(saldo))
 else:
     print("EMPATE!!!")
     print("O Jogador1 escolheu:", str(escolha1))
     print("O Jogador2 escolheu:", str(escolha2))
return saldo , saldo2
```

### função para rodar o jogo

```
def jogoroda(jogo_roda,rodada):
##declaracao de saldo de dinheiro
   while jogo_roda == True:
       while rodada != 3:
          if rodada == 1:
              sorteio_Cartas(jogador,jogador2,rodada)
              jogoroda(jogo_roda,rodada)
          elif rodada == 2:
              sorteio_Cartas(jogador,jogador2,rodada)
              jogoroda(jogo_roda,rodada)
          elif rodada == 3:
              sorteio_Cartas(jogador,jogador2,rodada)
              jogoroda(jogo_roda,rodada)
          else:
              jogo_roda = False
      else:
          print("Fim de jogo")
      print("Esta é a primeira {} Rodada!!".format(rodada))
      print("O jogador 1 {} reais!!!!, Boa sorte! ".format(saldo))
      print("As Cartas do jogador1 são: "+str(jogador))
      print("-"*32)
      aposta = float(input("Porfavor Faca uma Aposta: "))
      escolha1 = input("Jogador 1 escolha uma carta: ")
      print("O jogador 2 {} reais!!!!, Boa sorte! ".format(saldo2))
      print("As Cartas do Jogador 2 são: ",str(jogador2))
      print("-"*32)
      aposta2 = float(input("Porfavor Faca uma Aposta: "))
      escolha2 = input("Jogador 2 escolha uma carta: ")
      escolha_Cartas(escolha1,jogador)
      print(escolha1)
      escolha_Cartas2(escolha2,jogador2)
      print(escolha2)
      comparacao(escolha1,escolha2,aposta,aposta2,dinheiro,dinheiro2,saldo,saldo2,res,res2)         







     # chama a Execução
     jogoroda(jogo_roda,rodada)
```

Comment: O que seriam as "cartas" em um jogo de pedra, papel e tesoura?

Comment: no caso as "cartas" nesse jogo seriam o conteudo da lista dos jogadores , por exemplo na lista jogador2 tem três strings , essas seriam as "cartas"

Answer (score -1):

A variavel 'rodada' está sendo declarada duas vezes sem ser utilizada no início do programa. Primeiro 'rodada = 0' depois 'rodada = 1' sem que nada tenha acontecido.

A funcionalidade da variavel 'jogo_roda' compete com a função da variavel 'rodada', e ambas não são necessárias antes da função jogoroda(), então não precisam ser declaradas antes, muito menos precisam ser passadas dentro de todas as outras funções.

Dentro de jogoroda() tudo abaixo da linha 'print("Fim de jogo")' será alcançado APENAS quando rodada>3, porém a única função que atualiza o valor de rodada é sorteio_Cartas() e você não está capturando esta informação ( quando você altera 'rodada' dentro de um função, você está alterando uma cópia de 'rodada'). Fora da função o valor não será atualizado.
[image: Fora da função o valor não será atualizado]

Então o jogo roda diversas vezes sempre achando que é a primeira rodada. Além disso, sua função jogoroda() chama a sí mesma, mas não está preparada para isso. Vários outros problemas com variaveis vão aparecer.

Considere reescrever o programa fazendo um dicionário com os jogadores sendo as chaves e o saldo de cada jogador sendo o valor armazenado. O sorteio das cartas dos jogadores deve acontecer imediatamente antes do momento em que os jogadores farão a escolha da carta. Na mesma função você sorteará as cartas, os jogadores escolherão a cartas usada, e você escolherá o vencedor e atualizará o saldo. Acima dessa função você faz um contador de rodadas para finalizar o jogo. Lembre que alterações de variaveis dentro de uma função não são carregadas pra fora. Você tem que capturar as alterações você mesmo.

[image: Você tem que capturar as alterações você mesmo.]